# Reinstall of OS after CPU Upgrade needed?

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, cpu

I recently upgraded my CPU from an Athlon II X2 250 to the Athlon II X4 610E(45W 4 cores -- can't beat the efficiency).  Is an ubuntu reinstall required?

Comment: The only time I'm ever had a problem with ubuntu and hardware changes was when I swapped graphics cards from ATI->Nvidia and forgot to enable the generic vesa driver before the swap. I've literally transplanted a hardrive from my old laptop (2004 HP) to my new (2009 Lenovo) and ubuntu booted up and ran like a champ.

Comment: Why ask?  If you already did the upgrade, and the system works, then the answer is obviously no.

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't need to reinstall, Ubuntu is very, very accepting of hardware changes.

A good example of this was I have a Dell Latitude here that has a core two duo p9700 processor, nVidia Quadro graphics, two gigabytes of ram. That recently failed (my own fault) so to transfer the files off of the hard disk within it I put the hard disk into my other laptop, which is a Compaq Presario which has a Pentium dual core processor, three gb of ram, Intel graphics, a very different system. To my surprise it booted up from the old install on my Latitude with absolutely no driver issues at all. I was absolutely amazed. After I figured this out I tested it by hooking the hard disk up to my Desktop computer which contains an AMD Sempron single core processor along with nVidia Gforce 9600gt graphics card and four gb  of ram and still it booted with absolutely no issues.

This has to be one of my favourite things about Ubuntu because it makes things so much easier.

Comment: I recently replace all the hardware on my system except for the harddrive.  New mobo, CPU, RAM, DVD.  No reinstall required, definitely a pleasant surprise.  I had to reinstall Windows, though, presumably due to anti-piracy measures.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to reinstall Ubuntu for new hardware being recognized. Just boot up after plugging the power on it and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to use multiple cores depends on the kernel and if it was compiled with the SMP feature (Symmetric Multi Processing).  ([Ubuntu overview of SMP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel#SMP))  Since your last CPU was a dual core, it probably had the SMP kernel installed.  Your new quad core will also use the same SMP kernel.  (The SMP kernel will automatically adjust for the number of cores each time it is booted.)

To confirm that the kernel is able to see all four cores, check the `/proc/cpuinfo` file.  For instance, a quad-core cpu should have four `core` lines:

```
dan@titan:~$ grep ^core /proc/cpuinfo
core id             : 0
core id             : 1
core id             : 2
core id             : 3
```

Comment: Man, that documentation is old.  All the Ubuntu kernels have support for SMP (unless you've deliberately installed linux-image-386, and even then that kernel has been dropped since Ubuntu 10.04).

Answer (score 2):

In general the nature of Linux is such that it starts each time as if it is loading on a fresh system (to put it simply). Unless you do something such as putting your hard drive in a new system you won't have to do a thing.

Comment: Even then, you'd usually not have to do anything?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad depends....