# Do i need to reinstall ubuntu after GPU/CPU upgrade

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics, amd-graphics

I now have PC with **Intel Celeron G530**(dual core 2.4GHz) **4GB ram**, **Amd HD 5450**(1gb GDDR3)and Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome in dual boot.
I plan to upgrade my GPU to Radeon r7 360(2gb GDDR5),do i need after upgrade to reinstall ubuntu because when i installed ubuntu drivers installed automatically.
And later to upgrade my CPU and MOBO.Do i need to reinstall after GPU and CPU pugrade.**I am new to linux** **and sorry for bad English**

Comment: Simple answer is no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reinstall of OS after CPU Upgrade needed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65555/reinstall-of-os-after-cpu-upgrade-needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to reinstall whole operating system, but you might have to install drivers manually, which isn't difficult.